# Make a json object properly by retrieving data by MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am making a php project and I am currently hosted it in my local xammp server.
I need to connect this to an android application using volley library.
So I need to make a json object.In orders I have stored picture of the product and orders.php page that I retrieve it via orderno.
In orders.php page I can see all my orders with images.

When trying to make the json object I need get this image url.I try to get it via order no but all the times i can't get the correct url.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

[image]

This is for making that json object.

This is the link to the image current json which I got
[image]

I want to make my image URL like below image:
[image]

Comment: Please don't share image of your code. Please copy paste your code to the question.

Comment: I try it but i cant copy paste my php code.

Comment: just copy paste the code, let us edit it to proper format

Comment: Have you tried [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: Yeap i tried but i still getting the same url for the image misplace with "\" character.

Comment: Yeap i tried .now its working

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple issues with your PHP code. However, I tried the resolve most of them. Still if you see any issues let me know, I will try to help you. I will highlight the changes I did to the code, for you to understand.

Here goes the PHP code to retrieve values:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

include("config.php");
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ORDERS");

if (!empty($result)) {
// check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    // user node
    $response["orderdata"] = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $orderdata = array();
        $i = $row["ITEM_ID"];
        $url = "http://localhost/Online_shopping/admin/'$i'.jpg";
        $orderdata["url"] = $url;
        $orderdata["item_id"] = $row["ITEM_ID"];
        $orderdata["price"] = $row["PRICE"];
        $orderdata["size"] = $row["SIZE"];

        array_push($response["orderdata"], $orderdata);
    }

    // success
    $response["response_code"] = 200;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["response_code"] = 999;

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// no product found
$response["response_code"] = 999;

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

1. You need to first setup a connection with your database which is located in a particular server.
2. Using that connection, you need to query in your table to get the data.
3. **mysql_query**, **mysql_fetch_array** is deprecated. You have to use **mysqli** instead of **mysql**.

Lastly, you can go through [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) post to learn simple basic operations using PHP.

Comment: Yeap i havent mentioned all of the code cause this is one php script to retrive data.I tried your way but thing is i still retrieving my image url as "http:\/\/localhost\/Online_shopping\/admin\/'foot2'.jpg" through the json obect.All other things are correct.this "/" comes with "\" when pushing in to array and encoding in to json

Comment: do u know what to do get the correct image url?{"products":[{"img":"http:\/\/localhost\/Online_shopping\/admin\/'foot2'.jpg","pname":"Tresmode Ladies Pump Shoes","itemno":"foot2","price":"Rs1690","size":"Medium"},{"img":"http:\/\/localhost\/Online_shopping\/admin\/'k4'.jpg","pname":"W Mix and match kurta ","itemno":"k4","price":"Rs1079","size":"Medium"},{"img":"http:\/\/localhost\/Online_shopping\/admin\/'cs2'.jpg","pname":"United Colors of Benetton Mens","itemno":"cs2","price":"Rs1999","size":"Medium"}]} here is the entire json object i retrieved

Comment: I change as you have said my enire format.Now its working properly.Thanks Saumik.

Comment: You can get the string value of `img` and replace all the "\" from the string.  Like this -- `String newURL= oldURL.replace("\", "");`

Comment: Yeap.Got it .Now its working nicely.I retrieve the json object properly.Thanks Saumik.!

Comment: @NavodNeranjan -- If it is working correctly, can you please accept my answer? Or up-vote my answer if it had helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: yeap.thing is i still dont have enough reputation to upvote.Thats why.I am still a new one to community.

Comment: Yeap.Thank you very much

Comment: @NavodNeranjan -- Buddy you did not accept my answer yet! :) Please do it so that it will help others in getting their issue resolved.